# Rules and Variables

Tags: commerce, rules

I have one rule that creates a variable and adds a value to it.

I have now created a second rule that needs to check the value of the variable created in the first rule. I am trying to use the "Data Comparison" option. However I can't see the variable in the Data Selector.

Is it possible to use Variables created in one rule with another rule and if so any ideas how to do it.

This question was marked as duplicate maybe by mistake. I notice one other question that is similar but is aimed at module code. I am trying to create my rules in the Rule UI. There is no other question on this site that covers this topic. If there is then please, please, please provide the link and then close the question.

Thanks
Simon

Comment: Hi Simon, is the next question you asked (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59472/rules-ui-accessing-a-variable-created-in-another-rule) the same as this one? I can't quite tell, but if they are I'll re-open this one and merge in the other one with the answer

Comment: I also can't quite tell what the difference is between this question and the "other one", so looks like a dup to me?